# file operation in shell script

Tags: shell-script, files

I have a requirement to extract the number of lines starts with with unique pattern and print the pattern and number of occurrences as below format. pattern delimeter should be /.

file.txt contains the entries as below

```
path1/path1/Dockerfile
path1/path1/path1.config
path2/inputdir/Dockerfile
path2/inputdir/path1.config
path2/outputdir/path1.config
pipelines/pipeline1.yml
pipelines/jobs/job1.yml
```

and output should be as below

```
path1=2
path2=3
pipelines=2
```

I am using awk as below, but it need a pattern match as a input(like path1, whereas this needs to be dynamically driven.

```
awk '/^path1/{a++}END{print a}' files.txt
```

Could someone suggest on this . Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to keep track of one count for each top-level directory name.  This is easiest done using an associative array in `awk` with the directory name being the key. We may then read each line as a set of `/`-delimited fields to easily have access to the directory name (the 1st field):

```bash
awk -F / '{ count[$1]++ } END { for (name in count) printf "%s=%s\n", name, count[name] }' file
```

With a multi-line layout of the code:

```bash
awk -F / '
    { count[$1]++ }
    END {
        for (name in count)
            printf "%s=%s\n", name, count[name]
    }' file
```

This is *reminiscent* of your own code, but does not try to match a particular string at the start of each line. Instead, given that the fields are delimited by `/` (which we arrange with `-F /` on the command line), we pick out the first field with `$1`.

The first field's value is then used as a key in an array called `count`.  Whereas you use a scalar variable, `a`, an array in `awk` can be used to keep track of many different values at once, and we just increment the value associated with the first field.

In the end, we loop over all collected keys in the `count` array and print them out together with the value associated with each key.

Note that the output is unordered and that depending on what `awk` you are using, it may be presented in a different order each time you run the command.

---

If the output format is of less importance, then you may also solve this by cutting out the first field with `cut`, sorting it (if the data is not already sorted), and then counting the unique strings:

```bash
$ cut -d / -f 1 file | sort | uniq -c
   2 path1
   3 path2
   2 pipelines
```

Comment: Thanks, this solves my purpose.

Comment: For the second: `cut -d / -f 1 file.txt | sort | uniq -c |sed -n "s/ *\([0-9]*\) \(.*\)/\2=\1/p"`